# X,Y,Z are independent identically distributed continuous then $X > Y \cap X > Z$ and $Y > Z$ are independent

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables

I'm trying to prove that

> If $X,Y,Z$ are independent identically distributed continuous random variables then
> the events $X > Y \cap X > Z$ and $Y > Z$ are independent.

I start with proving $P(X > Y \cap X > Z \cap Y > Z) = P(X > Y \cap X > Z) P(Y > Z)$, that means$$\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^3} 1_{x > y} 1_{y > z} \, d(P_X(x) \otimes P_{Y}(y) \otimes P_{Z}(z)) = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^3} 1_{x > y} 1_{x > z} \, d(P_X \otimes P_{Y} \otimes P_{Z}) \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^3} 1_{y > z} \, d(P_X \otimes P_{Y} \otimes P_{Z})$$
then try to use the Fubini-Tonelli theorem to prove that without success.

Edit: I've forgotten to add the "identically distributed" condition for $X,Y,Z$, sorry.

Comment: Have you considered disproving the statement?

Comment: Indeed, if these random variables are not identically distributed, the statement is wrong as pointed out by Mike. I've finally proved that it's true for the case of independent identically distributed variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually not true in general.

HINT: Consider $X,Y,Z$ mutually independent random variables; $X$ taking on the uniform distribution on $[0,1/2+\epsilon]$ for some *small* positive number $\epsilon$; $Y$ taking on the uniform distribution on $[1/2,1]$, and $Z$ taking on the uniform distribution on $[0,3/2]$. Then what is
${\bf{P}}[Y>Z]$, or at least, how does it compare to
$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} {\bf{P}}[Y>Z| \ (X>Y) \cap (X>Z)]$.

Indeed, [informally] let $A$ be the event $\{(X > Y) \cap (X>Z)\}$. Then $Z|A$ would vary between $0$ and $1/2+\epsilon$, whereas $Y|Z$ would be at least $\frac{1}{2}$, which means that ${\bf{P}}[Y>Z|A]$, would go to $1$ as $\epsilon$ vanishes. Compare to ${\bf{P}}[Y>Z]$, which is if nothing else no greater than $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry for forgetting to add "identically distributed" condition for the random variables.

Answer (score 0):

Since $P(Y > Z) = P(Y < Z)$ and $P(Y > Z) + P(Y < Z) = 1$ then $$P(Y > Z) = \frac{1}{2}$$Similarly $P(X > Y > Z) = P(X > Z > Y)$ then $$P(X > Y > Z) = \frac{1}{2} P(X > Y \cap X > Z)$$So$$P(Y > Z) \times P(X > Y \cap X > Z) = P(X > Y > Z) = P\left(Y > Z \cap \left(\left(X > Y\right) \cap X > Z\right)\right)$$that means $X > Y \cap X > Z$ and $Y > Z$ are independent.